Unable to load transpiler to transpile @angular/platform-browser
I've been trying to update an Angular2 project to a more recent version of Angular. Currently it's using Angular 15.2.10 and I've gone through a number of errors already but this one is proving difficult to resolve. The application builds successfully but the browser console is giving an error where it's not transpiling @angular/browser-platform and I'm not sure why.
I've already looked at adding "plugin-babel" as a transpiler in systemjs.config.js but that then gives a completely different error regarding a nullish coalescing operator in @angular/common/http.
Console error (@angular/platform-browser)
Unable to load transpiler to transpile http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/esm2020/index.mjs

Console error (@angular/common/http)
(index):72 
 (SystemJS) http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/common/esm2020/http/src/interceptor.mjs: Unexpected token (52:80)
      50 |     return (req, handler) => {
      51 |         if (chain === null) {
    > 52 |             const interceptors = inject(HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, { optional: true }) ?? [];
         |                                                                                 ^
      53 |             // Note: interceptors are wrapped right-to-left so that final execution order is
      54 |             // left-to-right. That is, if `interceptors` is the array `[a, b, c]`, we want to
      55 |             // produce a chain that is conceptually `c(b(a(end)))`, which we build from the inside
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token (52:80)

systemjs.config.js
(function(global) {
  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    '@angular/common/http':       'node_modules/@angular/common/esm2020/http',
    '@angular/common/esm2020/src/directives/ng_optimized_image':          'node_modules/@angular/common/esm2020/src/directives/ng_optimized_image',
    'node-uuid':                  'node_modules/node-uuid',
    'ngx-bootstrap':              'node_modules/ngx-bootstrap',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
    'rxjs/operators':             'node_modules/rxjs',
    'moment':                     'node_modules/moment/moment.js',
    'dragula':                    'node_modules/dragula/dist/dragula.min.js',
    'ng2-dragula':                'node_modules/ng2-dragula',
    'angular2-highcharts':        'node_modules/angular2-highcharts',
    'highcharts':                 'node_modules/highcharts',
    'highcharts/highstock.src':   'node_modules/highcharts/highstock.js',
    'plugin-babel':               'node_modules/systemjs-plugin-babel/plugin-babel.js',
    'systemjs-babel-build':       'node_modules/systemjs-plugin-babel/systemjs-babel-browser.js',
    'tslib':                      'node_modules/tslib/tslib.js',
    'zone.js':                    'node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone.umd.js'
  };

  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':           { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    '@angular/common/http': { main: 'index.mjs',  defaultExtension: 'mjs' },
    '@angular/common/esm2020/src/directives/ng_optimized_image': { main: 'index.mjs',  defaultExtension: 'mjs' },
    'rxjs':          { main: 'dist/cjs/index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs/operators': { main: 'dist/cjs/index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'ngx-bootstrap': { main: 'esm2020/index.mjs', defaultExtension: 'mjs' },
    'ngx-bootstrap/modal': { main: 'esm2020/index.mjs', defaultExtension: 'mjs' },
    'dragula':       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'ng2-dragula':   { defaultExtension: 'mjs', main: 'esm2020/ng2-dragula.mjs' },
    'node-uuid':     { main: 'uuid.js', defaultExtension: 'js'},
    'angular2-highcharts': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js'},
    'highcharts':    { main: 'highcharts.js', defaultExtension: 'js'},
  };
  var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'forms',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'router',
    'upgrade',
  ];
  
  // Individual files (~300 requests):
  function packIndex(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'esm2020/index.mjs', defaultExtension: 'mjs' };
  }
  
  // Add package entries for angular packages
  ngPackageNames.forEach(packIndex);
  
  var bsPackageNames = [
    'modal',
    'utils',
    'component-loader',
    'positioning',
    'focus-trap'
  ];
  
  function bsIndex(pkgName) {
    packages['ngx-bootstrap/'+pkgName] = { main: 'esm2020/index.mjs', defaultExtension: 'mjs' };
  }

  // Add package entries for angular packages
  bsPackageNames.forEach(bsIndex);

  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages,
    paths: {
      'ng2-dragula/*': 'node_modules/ng2-dragula/',
    },
    //transpiler: 'plugin-babel',

  };
  System.config(config);
})(this);


ts.config.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "System",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "ES2020"
    ],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "node",
      "jasmine",
      "jQuery",
      "core-js"
    ],
    "useDefineForClassFields": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
    ]
}

package.json
{
  "name": "", // Name removed for privacy
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && sass assets/scss/main.scss:assets/css/main.min.css --style compressed && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "dev": "node ./development.js",
    "lite": "lite-server"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.2.10",
    "@angular/cli": "^15.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "^15.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.2.10",
    "@angular/core": "^15.2.10",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.2.10",
    "@angular/localize": "^18.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^15.2.10",
    "@angular/router": "^15.2.10",
    "@angular/upgrade": "^15.2.10",
    "@types/core-js": "^2.5.8",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.8",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.42",
    "@types/node": "^20.14.11",
    "angular2-highcharts": "0.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "bootstrap-datepicker": "^1.6.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "dragula": "^3.7.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^2.2.4",
    "moment": "2.0.0",
    "ng2-dragula": "^3.2.0",
    "ng2-select": "^1.0.3",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^9.0.0",
    "node-uuid": "^1.4.7",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "^7.4.0",
    "systemjs": "^0.19.42",
    "systemjs-plugin-babel": "^0.0.25",
    "tinymce": "4.3.12",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "zone.js": "^0.14.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.10.4",
    "codelyzer": "0.0.23",
    "colors": "1.4.0",
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "connect": "^3.4.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^2.0.11",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-exec": "^2.1.2",
    "gulp-minify": "^0.0.12",
    "gulp-nodemon": "^2.1.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-rev": "^7.1.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-usemin": "^0.3.23",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "serve-static": "^1.11.1",
    "systemjs-builder": "^0.15.23",
    "tslint": "^6.0.0"
  }
}

Any help would be appreciated :)

Yeah don't use systemjs. Why don't you rely on the Angular CLI ?
